# In Xalan XSLT 1.0, how to pass a variable to a template match?

Tags: xslt, xpath, xalan

We are using Xalan XSLT 1.0 in Java and we want to pass a variable to a template match to avoid hard-coding element names in the XSL file. The style sheet compiles, but the date returned is wrong. Are we using the correct syntax?

Possible XML inputs...

```
 <books>   
    <book/>
    <book/>
 </books>

 <dvds>
     <dvd/>
     <dvd/>
 </dvds>


<xsl:variable name="matchElement" select="'book'"/>
<!-- OR -->
<xsl:variable name="matchElement" select="'dvd'"/>

<xsl:template match="/*[local-name() = $matchElement]">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `xsl:template`:

```
<xsl:template match="/*[local-name() = $matchElement]">
```

is matching from root.

Either remove the `/` from `/*` or change it to `//*` (depending on how the rest of your stylesheet is designed).

Also, if you use `xsl:param` instead of `xsl:variable`, you can set the value from the command line.

Comment: What's the syntax for supplying arguments from the command line to the xslt processor?

Comment: not sure who down-voted it, but it worked for me, don't lose sleep over a down vote, there are greater tragedies in the world :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your variable syntax is correct, but note that it is technically illegal to use variable or parameter references in XSLT 1.0 match patterns. It is possible, however, that Xalan has implemented this behavior outside of the standard. (@DevNull's comment about your expression also applies.)

Comment: Yes, I believe this is correct. Variable references in match patterns are not allowed by XSLT 1.0, but they are allowed in XSLT 2.0, and they are allowed in Xalan, despite the fact that in all (most?) other respects it implements XSLT 1.0.

Comment: I actually didn't realize this was a part of the spec until I started answering questions on SO, because both Firefox and Xalan (and I'm sure many others) *do* allow match patterns to contain variable references in their implementations of "XSLT 1.0"

Comment: Yes. I think I recall the history: it was allowed in working drafts of XSLT 1.0 until a very late stage. Then I raised a bug report asking what happened if there was a cyclic dependency, and the WG responded by banning the use of variables in patterns; but a number of implementations that had already provided this facility decided not to withdraw it.