# xsl:variable doesn't work within xsl:for-each

Tags: xslt, apache-fop

I have the following XSL:

```
<xsl:key name="Hosts" match="Report/Host" use="ID"/>
...
<xsl:for-each select="Report/Host[count(. | key('Hosts', ID)[1]) = 1 and Factor = 8]">
 <xsl:variable name="ThisID" select="ID" />
 <xsl:for-each select="/Report/Host[count(. | key('Hosts', Name)[1]) = 1]">
  <xsl:for-each select="key('Hosts', Name)[ID = $ThisID]">
   <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

When I run it through FOP 1.1 (not sure if fop is to blame here), I get this error:

```
SEVERE: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/temp/fop/fop-1.1/pdf-report.xml; lineNumber: 243; columnNumber: 180; java.lang.RuntimeException: Variable not resolvable: ThisID
...
; SystemID: file:/C:/temp/fop/fop-1.1/pdf-report.xml; Line#: 243; Column#: 180
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Variable not resolvable: ThisID
```

Line 243, is this line:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Report/Host[count(. | key('Hosts', ID)[1]) = 1 and Factor = 8]">
```

I cannot see why this doesn't work

Comment: My first question would be whether you're really running the version of the stylesheet that you think you are, since line 243 that you showed doesn't involve `ThisID` at all. On another tack, what is the definition of the key 'Hosts'? Does it attempt to use `$ThisID`?

Comment: Yes, I know I am running the right one, and I know it is showing the wrong line, i.e. 243, because if I remove that block that references the ThisID and re-run it, it works (i.e. no error, PDF is generated, minus this section)

Comment: `Hosts` doesn't use $ThisID, btw if I use <xsl:value-of select="$TestID" /> it shows the value

Comment: OK. So you're saying that if you remove the *innermost for-each*, it runs w/o errors? Weird... And the name of your XSLT stylesheet is `pdf-report.xml`? Or is the line number referring to your input file?

Comment: Yes, if I remove the for-each that references $ThisID it shows no error, pdf-report.xml is my bad naming convention for an XSLT file :S, if I put instead of the innermost for-each <xsl:variable select="$ThisID" /> I get the value I am trying to use

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using -- and if the answer is "Xalan", are you using the known-to-have-issues one that ships with Sun Java, or the current version downloaded from Apache?

Comment: OK I think I understand the symptoms. No idea about the cause. :-) But it would be enlightening to try a different XSLT processor, such as the excellent Saxon, and see if you encounter the same problem.

Comment: I am using `fop`, how can I find out whether it is using Xalan or something else? I download fop-1.1-bin.zip from their (Apache) site.

Comment: This definitely looks like an XSLT processor bug to me.

Comment: So what can I do @MIchaelKay ?

Comment: I also tried fop-1.0, I will try fop-0.9x in a few minutes, in either case same error

Comment: I can verify that also 0.95 has the same error, in the same place

Comment: As per the post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041838/in-xalan-xslt-1-0-how-to-pass-a-variable-to-a-template-match, it appears that is illegal to do searches with xsl:parameter / xsl:variable, any idea what is the alternative?

Comment: What that answer says is that it's illegal to use parameters / variables in *match patterns*. But you're not trying to use one in a match pattern; you're trying to use one in an XPath expression, where they are perfectly legal.

Comment: @nrathaus (So what can I do?) (a) verify that it is a bug by trying it with a different processor, (b) either switch to a processor that doesn't have the bug, or try and get the supplier to fix the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the error, it was not because of this element, Xalan is just not good at telling you the problem.

I had an error before it, which didn't cause a "stop" to the rendering, but did cause any additional xsl:variable to go unprocessed, an in turn, not allow anything to reference them.

The debugging went like this:

1. I made a mockup of my data, with the smallest data set I could
2. I made a bock of the above code to run on its own
3. It rendered ok
4. I knew that the XSL was good, but something else was stopping it from working
5. I started commenting the XML (original)  until it worked
6. I uncommented everything until it stopped working
7. I zeroed down on this

XSL statement:

```
<xsl:variable name="HostURIRequestSuffix">
 <xsl:if test="/Report/Scan/ScanDetails/SelectedHostReport = 'true'">
  <xsl:call-template name="GetHostsURL"/>
 </xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>
```

And this error:

```
file:/C:/temp/fop/fop-0.95/pdf-report.xml; Line #20; Column #48; org.xml.sax.SAXException: ElemTemplateElement error: GetHostsURL
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: ElemTemplateElement error: GetHostsURL
```

For some reason, this causes any additional xsl:variable to get ignored, while the rest of the rendering works perfectly, once I fixed this, everything works, thanks guys for the help

Comment: Wow, an error severe enough to cause other statements to be completely ignored, yet the processor went ahead and continued to process the rest of the stylesheet? (Without reporting the initial error?) I'd call that an insidious bug. I hope you report it (or find an existing report and upvote it.)

Comment: It appears to be a "well known" issue in Xalan, where it gives a Severe error, but continues to render everything as if nothing happened. In any case, I reported it, let wait and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for reporting it. Can you give here a link to the bug tracker entry, for completeness?

Comment: I wrote one of the developers an email, I haven't seen any bugtracker report entry yet